# Unexpected tail of the floating point from using arange loop to name the columns

Tags: python

I tried to create some numbers and rename the output columns with the `np.arange` loop as the following:

```
def conditional_zero_column(filename="random.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    for i in np.arange(0.6,1.0,0.01):
        df['reject'+str(i)] = np.where(df['expected_discount'] < i, df['expected_discount'], i)
        df['reject'+str(i)] = np.where(df['reject'+str(i)] >= i, df['reject'+str(i)], 0.0)
        df.to_csv("random_data4.csv", index=False)
```

The conditional number part worked for me.

The columns' names were fine between columns `reject0.6-reject0.68`.
After that, all columns' names turned to `reject` with the unexpected numbers, e.g., `reject0.6900000000000001`, `reject0.8000000000000002`, `reject0.9900000000000003`for all other columns as the attached the picture shows.

[column names]    [image: 1]

I am curious why the numbers are different after 0.69. I tried to simply replace `np.arange` with `np.linspace`, but it doesn't work for me.
Am I wrong with any part?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the tail of the floating point precision.  It is impossible to exactly represent most floats, and we end up with a tail that end at the numeric precision.

I think you can solve this by formatting the strings you are using for column names.

```py
def conditional_zero_column(filename="random.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    for i in np.arange(0.6, 1.0, 0.01):
        col = f'reject{i:.2f}'
        df[col] = np.where(df['expected_discount'] < i, df['expected_discount'], i)
        df[col] = np.where(df[col] >= i, df[col], 0.0)
        df.to_csv("random_data4.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me why it happened @James. You answer works perfectly